# How to open a "blank" window in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way (as complicated as I assume it is) to open a "blank" window in batch?

By "blank", I'm referring to the absence of any existing program. The equivalence of creating a frame with nothing in it, in another programming language such as Java.

[image: a blank window]

Comment: I am very courious, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ing.alfano To be honest, I don't know yet. I'm just curious myself if it was possible to create a program in Batch that could be ran with graphics not just inside a terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!-- :
@echo off
mshta.exe "%~f0"
exit /b %errorlevel%
-->

<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>


    <script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">

     window.resizeTo(800,600)
     </script>

</body>

</html>
```

?

you can even remove the taskbar and the frame with the hta tags.

Comment: More elegant than I thought! Though, would there be away to close the terminal (or make it virtually hidden) after launching the file while the new window stays open?

Comment: @Graviton use `start "" mshta.exe "%~f0"` on the third line (instead of direct call of the mshta)